# How do I mix and generate random strings(password) in C# .NET

Tags: c#, string, random, passwords, generator

I am learning C# and im trying to create a random string(password) generator.. I feel like its fun because its not the simple Hello World application

I am doing this in a windows form application

I am trying to mix all the

> public const string

and print it out to the TextBox2 in my project..
But the thing is I have no idea on how to actually mix them I was thinking about a for loop and check for every character.. Not really sure how I would do it..

Does anyone have any examples I could look over and try to understand how they are made? I saw one made with Linq here on SO but I couldnt really understand it because I am trying to involve check boxes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RandomCHaracterGenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form    
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        class RandomPWDGenerator
        {
            public const string CapitilizedLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            public const string NonCapitilizedLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            public const string Numbers = "0123456789z";
            public const string SpecialCharacters = "!@#$%^*()_+";

            private static Random rnd = new Random();        
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {

            }
        }

        public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
        public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

        [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
                         int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void topPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
            }
        }

        private void generateLbl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            generatePanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4d4d4d");
        }

        private void generateLbl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            generatePanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        private void generateLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at *any* of the eight posts under **Related** which have almost identical titles?

Comment: What's the difference between `length` and `amount`?

Comment: @itsme86 Ammount = How many passwords it generates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the strings into a list if their box is checked:

```
List<string> charSets = new List<string>();

if (cbLowercase.Checked)
    charSets.Add(NonCapitilizedLetters);
if (cbUppercase.Checked)
    charSets.Add(CapitilizedLetters);
if (cbNumbers.Checked)
    charSets.Add(Numbers);
if (cbSpecial.Checked)
    charSets.Add(SpecialCharacters);

if (charSets.Count < 1)
    // Tell them they need to check at least 1 box or whatever

int length = int.Parse(txtLength.Text);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (lenth-- > 0)
{
    int charSet = random.Next(charSets.Count);
    int index = random.Next(charSets[charSet].Length);
    sb.Append(charSets[charSet][index]);
}

string password = sb.ToString();
```

- DISCLAIMER: `Random` should be avoided for creating a cryptographically strong password. Something like [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be used instead.

Comment: I think I missed something.. I redid the code just a tiny bit and it says Error CS0103 The name 'length' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

A great way to learn is to take a look on a real password generation.

You can take an open source password manager Keepass and see what's happening there.

See files KeePassLib\Cryptography\PasswordGenerator in the source from http://keepass.info/download.html